# removing <ul> from django forms validation errors

Tags: django, django-forms

In Django the {{ form.field.errors }} gives the validation error for a field. But it always displays it as unordered list (). But I just want the error message. Is there a way to get the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `{% for error in field.errors %}` and then output each error one by one, this will produce just the string containing the message rather than an unordered list. The docs explain this:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/forms/

Comment: Also useful is {% for error in form.non_field_errors %} (which the docs don't mention) to get to the errors that aren't tied to a single specific field.

Comment: Yea, I really wish the docs were better documented, they sometime leave something to be desired, even if the docs are pretty good for things that ARE documented.

Answer (score 24):

You can just use {{ form.field.errors|striptags }}.

Comment: Also works for ``{{ form.errors.FIELDNAME|striptags }}``

Answer (score 0):

In the Django template

```
<!-- If form errors exists -->
{% if form.errors %}

    <!-- For each field in form -->
    {% for field in form %}
            <!-- For each error in field -->
        {% for error  in field.errors %}
                    <!-- Output error text message only -->
            <div>{{error}}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```